# Send activity/update ios app to a user while in background

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am building my first app but wanted to know if there is a way to send updates or activity notifications to a user without a push notification.

These updates could include:

```
icon badge
Sound
Alert that appears on the lockscreen (I believe this is the push notification)
```

What can be done without requiring the user to give permission? I have tasks for the user at x time and want to remind them at that time.

Comment: You can use a push notification or a scheduled local notification. Both require the user to grant permission.

Comment: All background notifications require user permission? that is a bummer then

Comment: They have to grant permission, once, for your app to issue notifications. The user can change notification permissions through settings later

Comment: I just downloaded an alarm clock app that DID NOT ask me for notifications and still works by sounding the alarm at a particular time so there has to be a way

Comment: It may use background audio mode to make a sound but it can't send a notification without permission.

Comment: My question asks for sound too. So you can send sound in background? Anything else? Just no badges and no lock screen data.

Comment: You can make a sound, but you will need to play silence continually until it is time to make the sound. This is not battery friendly and Apple may well reject your app. You can't display a message. The other thing the app could do is schedule a reminder through your calendar if you give it permission

Comment: if an app tries to notify me without my permission, and/or if I didnt know which app is making all that noise, i would uninstall it asap! that stuff is just annoying.